# Sound problem while using ubuntu

Tags: sound, drivers

I could not hear audio.I install ubuntu 10 linux lucid and windows7.I am able to hear audio in windows but no sound in ubuntu. I have no sound card. How could I hear sound? My computers mother board is Gigabyte H55M-S2v.

Comment: Please add some hardware information to your question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into

Answer (score 2):

Follow the instructions provided at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingSoundProblems -- most likely it is something simple like muted audio or the wrong output setting.

To start troubleshooting the problem, run `ubuntu-bug audio` (either from a Terminal or using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>).